# "java not found" when I try to read a PDF file using the Tabula library

Tags: python, heroku, bots

I have a Python bot running on Heroku. When I try to read a PDF using Tabula I get this error:

> Еrror: tabula.errors.JavaNotFoundError: "java" command is not found from this Python process.Please ensure Java is installed and PATH is set for "java"

Why can't my bot find `java`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The documentation](https://pypi.org/project/tabula-py/) says

> `tabula-py` is a simple Python wrapper of [tabula-java](https://github.com/tabulapdf/tabula-java), which can read table of PDF

Heroku's buldpacks only contain what they need to provide. The Python buildpack doesn't include Java, so you're going to need to add [another buildpack](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-multiple-buildpacks-for-an-app).

Something like this should do it:

```
heroku buildpacks:set heroku/python
heroku buildpacks:add --index 1 heroku/java
```

After that, run `heroku buildpacks` and ensure that you see the Java buildpack first and the Python buildpack second. Redeploy and try again.

If you don't already have a `pom.xml` file you will also have to create one. Heroku gives [a minimal example in their documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-java#verify-that-your-pom-xml-file-is-set-up-correctly).

Comment: Now there are new errors
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tabula/wrapper.py", line 67, in _run
        return subprocess.check_output(args)
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 395, in check_output
        **kwargs).stdout
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 472, in run
        with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 775, in __init__

Comment: Also after that there was an error related to Java
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 1522, in _execute_child
 raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
And after that "During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:" there were errors related to Java

Comment: That's a different issue, @Murlodin, and we likely need more information. But a few ideas off the top of my head: Are you using the same version of Python (3.7) locally? Are you using the same versions of all of your dependencies locally? What are the specific Java errors? Note that all of this should go into a new question, not asked here in comments.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, now I will create a new question

Comment: I use python 3.7.4

Comment: My guess is that the specific Java errors will help answer your next question. Please make sure to include them.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/58564486/12270703  here is a new question

Comment: @Murlodin, if the "java not found" error is still there this question may require more attention. (a) You deployed again after adding the new buildpack, and saw both buildpacks being applied? (b) If you `heroku run bash` and then type `which java` what do you get back?

Comment: when you try Push, an error appears  
`remote: -----> App not compatible with buildpack: https://buildpack-registry.s3 amazonaws.com/buildpacks/heroku/java.tgz remote: Could not find a pom.xml file! Please check that it exists and i committed to Git.`

Comment: Every buildpack requires certain files. For Python, it's `requirements.txt` or `Pipfile` and `Pipfile.lock`. For Java it's `pom.xml`. If you don't have any dependencies you should be able to get away with something pretty basic [like this](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-java#verify-that-your-pom-xml-file-is-set-up-correctly). Add that file with valid content and deploy again.

Comment: (You should also delete your other two questions as they're exact duplicates of this one.)

Comment: Thank you, you helped, but there were warnings related to fonts and an error, https://stackoverflow.com/q/58582880/12270703

Comment: Okay, we're finally past the issue you originally asked about here. I'm glad I was able to help, and I hope you get an answer on that new question.

Answer (score 0):

To be specific on above answer mentioned by Chris, if someone still not able to solve the error I would like to mention that the link he has provided for pom.xml you need to just delete the `<dependencies>` tag  and `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` this. And just add pom.xml on to your root directory.